# MYSQLI SQL query over multiple tables fail

Tags: mysql, sql

I am very new to SQL and i need to retreive a number of attributes from different tables but. I am searching for images and details about a user by searching for them under their name.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name LIKE '%tim%' AND last_name '%smith%'
```

I need the following attributes in my result:

I will need all the details from table 1

account id and image from table 2

path from table 4

I have tried

```
SELECT table1.id table1.name table1.last_name table 2.account_id table4.path FROM table1 table 2 table4 WHERE table4.image_id = table 2.image AND table1.first_name LIKE '%tim%' AND table1.last_name LIKE '%smith%'
```

I am considering spilting this up into multiple queries which would solve this issue, however I am sure this can be done under a single query?, I am just not sure how to structre it, I have tried a number of times, but all queries fail in phpmyadmin

Hope someone can point me in the right direction? Below are an example of my tables, thanks in advance!

```
table1
------------
id (pk)
name
last_name

table 2
--------------
account id (pk)
id (fk)
image (holds image id from table 4)

table 3
-----------------
account id (fk)
image id (fk)
date

table 4
--------------------
image id (pk)
path
date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.account_id, t4.path
  FROM table1 t1
       INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
       INNER JOIN table4 t4 ON t4.image_id = t2.image
```

Comment: Thanks AlejoBrz, however I had to remove t1 as phpmyadmin did not see the table, replacing these and the query worked thanks

Answer (score 2):

So you have `INNER JOIN`s between `table1` & `table2`, and between `table2` & `table4`. In MySQL, `JOIN` implicitly means `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT
  table1.id,
  table1.name,
  table1.last_name,
  table2.account_id,
  table4.path
FROM
  table1
  JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
  JOIN table4 ON table2.image = table4.image_id 
WHERE table1.name LIKE '%tim%' AND table1.last_name LIKE '%smith%'
```

(**Edit**: Forgot to add in the original `WHERE` clause.)