# Mysqli LIKE statement not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm getting these weird errors, and I've been up and down the code, commenting and rewriting, and googling all the things.
Perhaps you guys will see what I'm not seeing:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('host','login','passwd','db');
if($mysqli->connect_errno > 0){ die('Cannot connect: '. $mysqli->connect_error); }
// See if there is one term or multiple terms
if (count($search) == 1) {
// If one term, search for that
$like = $search[0];
$stmt = "SELECT 
            gsa_committees.id,
            gsa_committees.committee,
            gsa_committees.appointer,
            gsa_committees.representatives,
            gsa_committees.contact,
            gsa_committees.category,
            gsa_committees.attachments,
            gsa_committees.labels,
            gsa_committee_reports.committee,
            gsa_committee_reports.title,
            gsa_committee_reports.author,
            gsa_committee_reports.link,
            gsa_funds.id,
            gsa_funds.fund,
            gsa_funds.attachments,
            gsa_funds.labels,
            gsa_meeting_minutes.title,
            gsa_meeting_minutes.link,
            gsa_officers.office,
            gsa_officers.dept,
            gsa_officers.name,
            gsa_representatives.program_dept,
            gsa_representatives.representatives,
            gsa_representatives.alternate
        FROM 
            gsa_committees,
            gsa_committee_reports,
            gsa_funds,
            gsa_meeting_minutes,
            gsa_officers,
            gsa_representatives
        WHERE 
            (gsa_committees.committee LIKE $like) AND   
                             gsa_committees.committee IS NOT NULL";
}
if(!$result = $mysqli->query($stmt)){ die('Bad query: '. $mysqli->error); }
```

This gives me this error message:

```
Bad query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%ARCHAC%) AND gsa_committees.committee IS NOT NULL' at line 34
```

Which I know isn't true. If I change that las part to just this:

```
WHERE gsa_committees.committee LIKE $like";
```

I get this error message:

```
Bad query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%ARCHAC%' at line 34
```

Everywhere I've looked, the string `"%".search."%"` seems to be the correct method, but my server doesn't seem to like it here.

Interesting side note: I have a different LIKE statement working on another page on the same server, this just won't work for some reason.

Thanks!

Comment: what is the value for $like variable that you are getting ?

Comment: Maybe have { and } around `$like`?

Comment: ^^ and is it quoted correctly

Comment: It's coming from a search box on another page: $term = $_POST['search'];

Answer (score 0):

Try putting single quotes around your search term ($like variable).

for example: (gsa_committees.committee LIKE '$like')

Comment: When I put single quote around $like, the page hangs (on posting page) and doesn't even render; no blank white page or any error message.

Comment: By putting a wild card (%) in front of the keyword you are searching for you are essentially breaking the index. This results in very very poor performance. 
So instead only use the percentage at the end of the keyword. i.e.
'search%' instead of '%search%'

Comment: This did not make any difference. I get nothing, no error message or results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the variable in quotes for like to work:

```
WHERE gsa_committees.committee LIKE '$like';
```

See reference documentation on [String Comparison Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html).

Comment: This did not make any difference.

Comment: @Kaceykaso, could you print that query and post the output along with the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like missing quotes:

```
"WHERE gsa_committees.committee LIKE '$like' ";
```

Answer (score -2):

Ok, I got it. The answer on this post solved my issue:
[MYSQLI SQL query over multiple tables fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862105/mysqli-sql-query-over-multiple-tables-fail)

As soon as I assigned the tables t1,t2,etc and did INNER JOIN, the results came in as expected, with %$search% or $search.
Thanks all!